# Why my servlet is not working in Eclipse IDE but in Google Chrome?

Tags: java, servlets

I am new in advance Java and getting problem in simple Login servlet program.

URL 1= http://localhost:8080/WelcomeProject 
  (-*it gives Login Page(htlm page)*)

URL 2=http://localhost:8080/WelcomeProject/WelcomeClass 
  (-*It prints message of my program*)

*Case number is below:*

1. When i am writing  both ULRs in Eclipse inbuilt browser and
   Google chrome its working fine IN both.
2. But after opening Login page through URL 1 when i am clicking to
   submit button it prints my program message in chrome
   browser(ie;working fine) but on eclipse browser shows -404
   error-resource not available.

*Using Tomcat 8.0.*

*Web.xml:*

```
<web-app> 
     <servlet> 
          <servlet-name> WelcomeClass</servlet-name> 
          <servlet-class>WelcomePackage.WelcomeClass</servlet-class> 
     </servlet> 
     <servlet-mapping> 
          <servlet-name>WelcomeClass</servlet-name>   
          <url-pattern>/WelcomeClass</url-pattern> 
     </servlet-mapping> 
 </web-app>
```

I didn't write whole program as it seems there is no problem in code b/c it's working correctly in chrome.
 Have i done any wrong any setting or what maybe the problem?

Comment: May be you are not configure properly, update your web.xml and update that code also where you are calling url2

Comment: URL 2 is just directly typing in the browser which gives the page  that shows message of my program which should have come after clicking submit button . This can be the configuration problem but is there anyway overcome it?

Comment: Did you update servlet-mapping in web.xml ? or please update your web.xml file!

Comment: If there would have been any error in XML file then it should also not work in chrome browser but in chrome when i click on submit it works fine. ie; code and mapping is correct ,what u say?

Comment: <web-app>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name> WelcomeClass</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>WelcomePackage.WelcomeClass</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>WelcomeClass</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/WelcomeClass</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>